# What determines whether podcasts are played individually or sequentially on an iPod?

Tags: ipod, podcasts

What determines whether podcasts are played individually or sequentially on an iPod?

Basically, I have a lot of podcasts on my iPod.
At one point, it would play just one podcast, and then stop. There was a period of a few weeks where I didn't listen to podcasts, and now when I go to listen to a podcast, when I finish one, the iPod begins playing the next.

This is an issue for me because I generally listen to podcasts when going to sleep. As such, the iPod generally goes through maybe ~10 podcasts overnight, and I loose track of where I was.

---

Basically, originally my iPod played podcasts one-by-one, I changed something, and now it does not.

However, I've been through the menus on the iPod, and I cannot see anything that looks like it would be related to the podcast playback behaviour. Whatever was changed, It's not readily apparent the effects it has.

Comment: As a side-note: DERP.

Answer (score 1):

I added *one* of the podcasts to a on-the-go playlist, and suddenly **all** the podcasts are playing individually, rather then sequentially.

I have no idea why adding *one* podcast to the in-the-go playlist affected **every** podcast, or what would actually be required to return the behaviour to the way it used to be (sequential playing), but there you are.

Answer (score -1):

Yup, this is kind of frustrating.  I haven't had the time to figure out whether it is a technical or configuration issue, but my solution is to put all podcasts that I want to play sequentially in a playlist.

So without playlist, they play individually, but in a playlist they play sequentially very well.

Comment: You're answer is the exact **opposite** of what I want. I'm having issues because all my podcasts are playing sequentially, and I want them to play *individually*